# Chrome taking a long time to load when I refresh the page

Tags: php, laravel, google-chrome

What I'm developing is when I reload the page, it's taking a long time to load all the content, but if I open it in a new tab, the same page opens quickly. Does anyone know what can it be?

What I'm developing is when I reload the page, it's taking a long time to load all the content, but if I open it in a new tab, the same page opens quickly. Does anyone know what can it be?

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Try clear out your cache
or
try this running this command `php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: Continue in the same way